# Which window function is faster?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

```sql
count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY a, b, c) * 10
```

This produces the same result as:

```sql
dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY a, b, c) * 10
```

Used in a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY a, b) ,
    a || b,
    count(*) OVER (
        PARTITION BY a, b
        ORDER BY a, b, c
    ) * 10 ,
    a2,
    b1,
    c1,
    cc1,
    c2,
FROM
  join ....
ORDER BY 1, 6;
```

I'm happy with my query result.
But should I appreciate one approach over the other and why?

Comment: I've never seen an `ORDER BY` in a `COUNT(*)` window function. Postgres is strange. Are you sure these are giving the same result?

Comment: can we have something reflecting HAVING

Comment: Could you show us the entire query, not just a section of the SQL

Comment: Regarding `HAVING` what you do is put your window function inside of a subquery and then do a `WHERE` in the main query. If you switch over to Snowflake or Teradata then they have a clause called `QUALIFY` that is the window function version of `HAVING` that allows you to skip the subquery step.

Comment: @JNevill: that's simply a running count and part of the way window functions are defined in the SQL standard.

Comment: `row_number() over (...)` would be third way to get the same result.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name All these years and I've never encountered that `Count(*) OVER (.. ORDER BY)`. Will keep it in mind.

Comment: even row_number nice may i say or weird

Comment: I think if you drop `a` and `b` from your order clause you'll save some sort space on PG 12, and therefore gain performance. It looks like PostgreSQL 12.6 at least is not smart enough to know that they can be ignored because they are constants within the partition. 13.6 seems good, but I'd drop them anyway.

Comment: I don't really understand this @David Aldridge
  it works and that's fine by me

Comment: You don't understand why including columns in the `order by` that are also in the `order by` is redundant, and a performance problem  in v12?

Comment: "Which window function is faster?"  Try them both and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `PARTITION BY a, b` there is no point in adding `a`or `b` to `ORDER BY`, like [David commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71386184/postgres-window-functions-performence-question#comment126180472_71386184).

So we simplify to:

```
count(*)     OVER (PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY c) * 10
dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY c) * 10
```

These two only happen to be equivalent while `c` is `UNIQUE`. Else they are not.

You'd need to define exactly what the number is supposed to signify, and show your table definition, and the exact query because joins can introduce duplicates and NULL values.

`row_numer()` or `rank()` are similar [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) ...

Performance is practically the same for all of them.

Comment: c is unique and not null of course a & b are not and they may not null